# Marooned in Minecraft: Need to get safely down from platform

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am on a high platform (Y=120) of cobblestone, single-block layer, 64x64, with nothing but a dozen iron pickaxes, on hard-core mode. I've been assured there is no water on the surface far below. I need to get down safely but do not know how to build down as I simply can't see the underside of the platform.

Note: I'm on hardcore mode, no cheats.

Is there a way to get down safely?

Comment: Do you know of a large, nearby body of water? If so, don't build down, build sideways until you're over it and jump off.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your predicament and perhaps show your inventory?

Answer (score 0):

UH...

1. If there is a support of blocks holding the platform up, just dig down.
2. If it is a floating platform, and if you have enough wood for a boat, craft one and row off the platform. You wont take any damage
3. This one requires a "glitch," but what you need to do is the jump off, pause the game just as you are about to hit the ground, and then un-pause. The pausing and resuming will negate the momentum you have gotten by falling.